# Setting app a separate Web API project and ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, vs-web-site-project

I am trying to consume a Web API service from another ASP.NET classic project (actually it is a native JS and Html Web application).
How can I configure these these **two separated projects** to talk with each other, on VS2012?

The final result would be:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/products
```

will return a list of products (JSON) by routing to ProductsController located on the WebAPI project,

And

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

will be routed to this page on the **Second** project - The native HTML/JS project.

How can I configure the logical to physical Directories in these two project?
Thanks!

Comment: So who calls the API? JS or ASP.NET Server-side code?

Comment: JS from a separate project in the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turned out it's pretty simple.
All I had to do is configure these both projects to share the same port on the local IIS:
So for the native JS/HTML (my second project) I use: 
[image: Project for the native JS/HTML - Has nothing to do with .NET!]

And the second project (WEB-API project):
[image]

That is it!
Now the js can consume the Web-Api!

Answer (score 1):

You just need a single project: ASP.NET Web API. I would put the index.html in the root and javascript files under scripts or js folder.

Normally static content such as js and html can be served directly by IIS in your ASP.NET Web API project. You need to make sure you add them to ignore rules in the startup:

```
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("*.js");
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("*.html");
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but you don't seem to understand my question. My first sentence had specifically mentioned I need to consume the service as if I can't have a single project (which of course can serve these purpose - this is the default..).